# How select unique years from table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have rows in a table in SQL Server 2008

[image: rows]

Tell me please how select only unique years from table?

P.S.: in this table unique year is 2013

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`YEAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx) function, with `DISTINCT` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR([date])
FROM Tablename;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad3bb/3)

This will give you:

```
| YEAR |
--------
| 2013 |
```

---

To use the order by clause, give it an alias and order by this alias not the original name like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR([date]) AS Year
FROM Tablename
ORDER By Year;
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT YEAR([date]) FROM table ORDER by date Desc` i have error `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.`

Comment: @LeoLoki - Give it an alias and order by this alias. See my edit.